# How to click on the highlighted today's day within the calendar with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, calendar

I'm trying to do an automation with selenium so that, for example, today it selects today's date, tomorrow selects tomorrow's date, without having to keep changing it, as it is a task completion that must occur every day, I would like to know how to select the day according to the current day automatically in the calendar, follows the page's HTML code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpc38.jpg)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>S</th>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>Q</th>
      <th>Q</th>
      <th>S</th>
      <th>S</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">1</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">2</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">3</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">4</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">5</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">6</div></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">7</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">8</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">9</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">10</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">11</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">12</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">13</div></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">14</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--active v-btn--rounded theme--light accent"><div class="v-btn__content">15</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-date-picker-table__current v-btn--rounded v-btn--outlined theme--light accent--text"><div class="v-btn__content">16</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">17</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">18</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">19</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">20</div></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">21</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">22</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">23</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">24</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">25</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">26</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">27</div></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">28</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">29</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">30</div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--text v-btn--rounded theme--light"><div class="v-btn__content">31</div></button></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow policies discourage questions asking for general recommendations. You will need to try some options and do research online before coming back with specific and/or technical questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe the HTML closely today's date i.e. ***16***  is highlighted as follows:

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="v-btn v-date-picker-table__current v-btn--rounded v-btn--outlined theme--light accent--text">
        <div class="v-btn__content">16</div>
    </button>
</td>
```

---

### Solution

To click on the highlighted day you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td > button.v-date-picker-table__current > div.v-btn__content").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td/button[contains(@class, 'v-date-picker-table__current')]/div[@class='v-btn__content']").click()
  ```

Comment: How did you get the CSS locator? I tried several ways to get it and I was just selecting the number, here's what was obtained when inspecting and copying the CSS: #app > div.v-menu__content.theme--light.menuable__content__active > div > div > div > div.v-date-picker-table.v-date-picker-table--date.theme--light > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4) > button > div

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in details within the Selenium Chat Room.

Comment: i don't have points enough

Comment: Hmm, in short you have to validate the CSS within the Chrome Console, keep on uniquely identifying the desired node using CSS_SELECTOR.